# Keras: Bug that depends on how many layers in network

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am having trouble with a seemingly arbitrary bug when using keras. I run into the error "NotFoundError: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output dense_3_target:0" when trying to build a model in keras. The error seems to depend on the number of layers I put in the network (bug when number of layers not equal to 4). Does anyone know what is going on here?

The code and error message:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

tf.reset_default_graph()


from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("mnist", one_hot=True)

X_train = mnist.train.images
y_train = mnist.train.labels
X_test = mnist.test.images
y_test = mnist.test.labels


# Hyper Parameters
n_features = 784
n_classes = 10
learning_rate = 0.5
training_epochs = 2


model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu', input_dim = n_features))
model.add(Dense(units = 50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(units = n_classes, activation = 'softmax'))

# Step 3: Compile the Model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy')

## Step 4: Train the Model
history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size = 100,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))
```

===================================================================

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-1076cda88cc6>", line 43, in <module>
    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,epochs=10,batch_size = 100,validation_data=(X_test,y_test))

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1037, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 199, in fit_loop
    outs = f(ins_batch)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2666, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2635, in _call
    session)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2587, in _make_callable
    callable_fn = session._make_callable_from_options(callable_opts)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1480, in _make_callable_from_options
    return BaseSession._Callable(self, callable_options)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1441, in __init__
    session._session, options_ptr, status)

  File "/Users/liyuan/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))

NotFoundError: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output dense_3_target:0
```

Comment: your code runs perfect on my pc no matter how many dense layers i add.
tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0, keras 2.1.5

Comment: I think the bug has something to do with the tf.reset_default_graph() command, if I don't use that command I don't get any bugs.

Comment: You are right. Using it again i got an error.